# Relation between two infinite products

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $a_{n} \in \mathbb{C} - \{0\}$ and is such that $\sum 1/|a_{n}| < \infty$. Let $f(z) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - z/a_{n})$ and $g(z) = \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty}(1 - z/|a_{n}|)$. For $0 < R < \infty$, why must $\inf_{|z| = R}|g(z)| \leq \inf_{|z| = R}|f(z)|$ and $\sup_{|z| = R}|f(z)| \leq \sup_{|z| = R}|g(z)|$?

Comment: Because $g(z)$ reaches its maximum and its minimum at two very specific points $z$ on the circle, independent on $(a_n)$...